# How can I call objective-c code from within an html file in a UIWebView?

Tags: iphone, html, objective-c, ibaction

So I know this type of thing is easily achieved in Java using JSP files, but I am wondering how I can mix code and html inside an iOS view. The reason I need to do that is that I have (local) html content being loaded into a UIWebView, and if they click on an html button, I need it to fire like an IBAction for example, and do some stuff locally.

Is this possible in XCode? What am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can not have Objective-C code mixed with an HTML file that runs locally on a `UIWebView`. That said, there are some workarounds that may fit your needs.

One that I've used, is to have the HTML link to a custom URL, and detect that on the appropriate method in the `UIWebView` delegate class, as follows:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
```

In that method, you would check for the `URL` schema you created by means of checking the `request` parameter, and then decide what selector to code on your Objective-C code.

Answer (score 4):

The following blog has shown a way to do this

http://davinccoder.wordpress.com/2011/06/28/call-ios-method-for-html-button-click/

Answer (score 2):

This is possible by using JavaScript event handlers that call your objective-c methods via the javascript [bridge](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/SafariJSProgTopics/WebKitJavaScript.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001483).

Comment: Unfortunately, the bridge is not available on iOS.